# How do count with inner join and multiple conditions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, conditional-statements

I want to a query that counts every time each color is used.

tbl_places is the main table that holds data from several enumeration tables. tbl_places holds the corresponding INT value for the color of specific floors in different buildings. `

tbl_paintcolor is an enumeration table with 2 columns: value and color.

I do not know how to relate the ON clause to the specific column I want to count in tbl_places.

```
SELECT
  `tbl_paintcolor`.`Color` AS Paint_Color,
  count(`tbl_places`.`blg1floor1_color`) AS Blg1Floor1,
  count(`tbl_places`.`blg1floor2_color`) AS Blg1Floor2,
  count(`tbl_places`.`blg1floor3_color`) AS Blg1Floor3
FROM `tbl_places` 
INNER JOIN `tbl_paintcolor` ON (`tbl_places`.`blg1floor1_color`=`tbl_paintcolor`.`Value` OR `tbl_places`.`blg1floor2_color`=`tbl_paintcolor`.`Value`)
GROUP BY `tbl_paintcolor`.`Color`
```

This query ends up counting the same column more or less.

How can I relate the conditional expressions in the ON clause to the columns I want to count in the SELECT clause?

I would like the query to output a column for each specific floor and each row counts the times that color is found. The output of this query would be structured:

```
╔════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ Color  ║ Blg1Floor1 ║ Blg1Floor2 ║ Blg1Floor3 ║ etc...
╠════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ red    ║     23     ║     23     ║     23     ║
║ orange ║     23     ║     23     ║     23     ║
║ yellow ║     23     ║     23     ║     23     ║
╚════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

etc

Thanks you for your time, and apologies if this is unclear, I am very new to SQL.

Comment: Your query doesn't strike me as being wrong.  What is your current output?

Comment: It outputs the same counts for each column. I think my problem is in the OR statement. I am looking for a better way to link the ON clause to my SELECT clause

Comment: It might help if you show us a reproducible example with data and the output the query gives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SUM()` with `CASE WHEN` will do the trick.

```
SELECT
      `tbl_paintcolor`.`Color` AS Paint_Color,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `tbl_places`.`blg1floor1_color` IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Blg1Floor1,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `tbl_places`.`blg1floor2_color` IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Blg1Floor2,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `tbl_places`.`blg1floor2_color` IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Blg1Floor3
    FROM `tbl_places` 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_paintcolor`
    ON (`tbl_places`.`blg1floor1_color`=`tbl_paintcolor`.`Value`
                               OR `tbl_places`.`blg1floor2_color`=`tbl_paintcolor`.`Value`)
    GROUP BY `tbl_paintcolor`.`Color`
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

i think you should try replacing the COUNT with SUM

```
SELECT
    `tbl_paintcolor`.`Color` AS Paint_Color,
    SUM(IF(`tbl_places`.`blg1floor1_color`=`tbl_paintcolor`.`Value`, 1, 0)) AS Blg1Floor1,
    SUM(IF(`tbl_places`.`blg1floor2_color`=`tbl_paintcolor`.`Value`, 1, 0)) AS Blg1Floor2,
    SUM(IF(`tbl_places`.`blg1floor3_color`=`tbl_paintcolor`.`Value`, 1, 0)) AS Blg1Floor3,
FROM `tbl_places` 
INNER JOIN `tbl_paintcolor` ON (
        `tbl_places`.`blg1floor1_color`=`tbl_paintcolor`.`Value` 
        OR `tbl_places`.`blg1floor2_color`=`tbl_paintcolor`.`Value`
        OR `tbl_places`.`blg1floor3_color`=`tbl_paintcolor`.`Value`
)
GROUP BY `tbl_paintcolor`.`Color`
```

or another way you can try is

```
SELECT `tbl_paintcolor`.`Color` AS Paint_Color,
    (SELECT COUNT(1) AS qty FROM `tbl_places` p1  WHERE p1.`blg1floor1_color`=`tbl_paintcolor`.`Value`) AS Blg1Floor1,
    (SELECT COUNT(1) AS qty FROM `tbl_places` p2  WHERE p2.`blg1floor2_color`=`tbl_paintcolor`.`Value`) AS Blg1Floor2,
    (SELECT COUNT(1) AS qty FROM `tbl_places` p3  WHERE p3.`blg1floor3_color`=`tbl_paintcolor`.`Value`) AS Blg1Floor3
FROM `tbl_paintcolor`
```

Comment: Thanks @David, your first script works better for me as I have a date column and I can use a where clause to focus the query